# Removing appended html in jQuery after setting class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with some validation, if it passes, it adds a processing class and also appends some html.

```
if (valid != '') {
    $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<p>Please correct the errors above.</p>' + valid).fadeIn('fast');
} else {

    $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('<p>Sending…</p>').fadeIn('fast');

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);

}
```

However I also have AJAX sending the form, and when it adds a success class, I need the html mentioned before to disappear.

```
$('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? "error" : "success")


if ($('form #form_ajax').hasClass('success')) { setTimeout("$('form #form_ajax').fadeOut('slow')", 2000);

}
```

I have tried fitting in `.remove('<p>')` into a few places with no luck. Am I going about this the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  Try adding this at the top of your AJAX block:

```
$('#form_ajax p').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<p>` created after the ajax send
the .remove start immediate
the ajax send works after a number of ms
so you are trying to remove an object that didn't exist yet

the best way is to use the complete ajax function

```
var request = $.ajax( 
url : "example.php"
,type: "POST" )

    request.done(function() { alert("success");    });
    request.fail(function() { alert("error");      });
    request.always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

you can remove the `<p>` in the .always() function
it fires after all is done

Comment: Readability is very poor and the code is poorly formatted. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `p` tags that are to be removed inside a div and distinguish then with a class name

```
if (valid != '') {
    $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<div id="wrapDiv"><p>Please correct the errors above.</p>' + valid+"</div>").fadeIn('fast');
} else {

    $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('<div id="wrapDiv"><p>Sending…</p></div>').fadeIn('fast');

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);

}
```

simply remove the div using `remove` where you want to remove the `p` tags

```
$(".wrapDiv").remove();
```